# Inequality contradiction

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

[image]

I do not get how $\bigcup_\limits{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(O_n\setminus(\bigcup_\limits{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(E_n))\subset\bigcup_\limits{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(O_n\setminus E_n)$?

Should it be instead $\bigcup_\limits{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(O_n\setminus(\bigcup_\limits{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(E_n))=\bigcup_\limits{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(O_n\setminus E_n)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you had equality that would imply that both sets are contained in the other ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in \bigcup_{n}{(O_n-\bigcup_{k}{E_k})}$ then $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \in O_n$ and $x \notin \bigcup_{k}{E_k}$. Then $x \notin E_k$, $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$. So $x \in O_n - E_k$, $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$. In particular $x \in O_n - E_n$. 
Hence, you have that $x \in \bigcup_{n}{O_n - E_n}$.

Note you should not be indexing both unions by the same n. Change one to k are something.

Comment: You are stating $x \in \bigcup_{n}{(O_n-\bigcup_{k}{E_k})}$ and $x \in \bigcup_{n}{O_n - E_n}$. So why are  not they equal if $x$ is in both of them? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Think about it this way, if you have two sets A,B such that $\forall x \in A$, $x \in B$ then what does this imply? It says that $A \subset B$. To show that two sets are equal what do you need to show? Well that $B \subset A$. Is this true in this case?